# AWS MySql connection error - 2003 from Jupyter notebook in VS Code

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql

I have an AWS MySQL db instance. It's open to public, I have made sure the security rules for inbound and outboud is set to fully open.
My friend is able to connect from Node JS, but it's not connecting from my work laptop or personal laptop, with PyMySql connect in Jupyter Notebook from VS code. It's not connecting from MySQL workbench either.

```
import pymysql
cnx=pymysql.connect(
database='mysqldb',
user='anveshjarabani',
password='xxxxxxxx',
host='mysqldb.c4mlxlyaw1ra.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
port=3304)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
```

I have tried pymysql, mysql, sql-connect, but to no avail.
Does this have to do with VPC or subnets? I am new to AWS database setups.
ERROR - OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on HOST TIMED OUT)